# Setting environment property in SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis, dts

I am trying to Execute a SSIS package located in SQL server 2012. It has a environment property. How can I set this in the package.

I am using the namespace Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.

I am attaching an image of the package.

[image]

Comment: I believe your question is how can I apply an Environment when I run an SSIS package as part of the project deployment model?

Comment: Yes, that is another way of saying it!